# How would one create a global variable that is constantly updating?

Tags: python

My current project is making a clock in Python. Using the datetime module, I can acquire the information I need. However, I'd like to be able to format how the time is printed. My plan is to first divvy up the output from the datetime module into it's separate parts, like so.

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now()
time.day()
```

Using this method, I could pick and choose which part of the time I want and arrange them in whatever order. The issue that I have found, however, is that, because `time`'s output is the time at which the variable was created, I need a way to constantly refresh `time` or specific parts of it, such as `time.day()` and still be able to access it. My next try was to use threading to run the refresh in the background.

```
import threading
import datetime
import time

def clock():
    while True:
        return datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(.1)

time = threading.Thread(target = clock())
time.start()
```

The issue that arises here, however, is that I cannot access the different bits that `time` contains. Obviously, `time.day()` will not work here, nor would `clock.day()`, because neither of them have that option.

**TL;DR**
I need a way to create a constantly updating variable so I can use and arrange the different bits of `time = datetime.datetime.now()` while keeping it up to date.

**Sub-question**
`variable = threading.Thread(target=[obj])`
Does `[obj]` *have* to be a function or is there some way to keep a loop of code running in a thread without running it as a function so the variable(s) running in the thread is global?

Comment: How are you running this script? Is it being imported into another module? Also side note: you're spawning a thread with an infinite runtime. That doesn't seem like your intended effect -- you want something that computes current date and time on command, right?

Comment: This sounds like a strange thing to do. Is there some motivation behind this?

Comment: Why not just use datetime.datetime.now() where you need it's value?

Comment: The main issue is that, by saving `datetime.datetime.now()` to a variable, I can't update it. I also just tried if `datetime.date.day` would give me the day but it won't. It seems that there's no way to get `.day` without saving it to a variable. But if I save it to a variable, I need a way to keep that variable updating to the clock values refresh when my clock look restarts.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, `time` variable is a thread, (should be initialized like `time = threading.Thread(target = clock)`, if you need the current time you can use `datetime.datetime.now()` in a `while` loop and do all your clock operation during one iteration time

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out I was looking at this all wrong. I don't need a constantly updating variable. I just need it to update when called. It's simple, really. Check out the code below!

```
import datetime

def second():
    sec = datetime.datetime.now()
    return sec.second
```

**Updoot**
Here's the finished program!

```
import os
import datetime
import time

def second():
    sec = datetime.datetime.now()
    return str(sec.second)

def minute():
  min = datetime.datetime.now()
  return str(min.minute)

def hour():
  hr = datetime.datetime.now()
  return str(hr.hour)

def day():
  dy = datetime.datetime.now()
  return str(dy.day)

def month():
  mn = datetime.datetime.now()
  return str(mn.month)

def year():
  yr = datetime.datetime.now()
  return str(yr.year)

while True:
  print(hour()+":"+minute()+":"+second()+"\n"+month()+"-"+day()+"-"+year())
  time.sleep(.1)
  os.system('cls')
```

Comment: This goes too far in the other direction; you don't necessarily want to call `now` separately for each component. Imagine `hour` and `minute` being called at `11:59:59` and `second` being called at `12:00:00`. Now your displayed time is off by a full minute. Call `now` *once*, and pass the returned value to each of your other functions.

Comment: Though in practice, you should be using `datetime.datetime.strftime` instead of building the time string yourself.  `datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S\n%m-%d-%y")` or similar.